# Cut Javascript string off

Tags: javascript, string, variables, substring

I've got a JavaScript variable called `cookie` with the the value

`__utma=43024181.64497201.1349454717.1349695569.1349702850.4; __utmz=43024181.1349679955.2.2.utmcsr=aerosoft-press.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; __utmc=43024181; __utmb=43024181.8.10.1349702850; language=de`

Now I want to cut off the `language=de` part of that string. I found a way to cut from behind:

```
cookie = cookie.substring(0,cookie.length-11);
```

But I just need the reverse way. Could anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean with "the reverse way"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two further options not currently presented, the first is using `indexOf()`:

```
var cookie = "__utma=43024181.64497201.1349454717.1349695569.1349702850.4;__utmz=43024181.1349679955.2.2.utmcsr=aerosoft-press.com|utmccn=referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/;__utmc=43024181; __utmb=43024181.8.10.1349702850; language=de",
    newCookie = cookie.substring(0,cookie.indexOf(' language'));
console.log(newCookie);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MaudF/).

And the second uses `lastIndexOf()`:

```
var cookie = "__utma=43024181.64497201.1349454717.1349695569.1349702850.4;__utmz=43024181.1349679955.2.2.utmcsr=aerosoft-press.com|utmccn=referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/;__utmc=43024181; __utmb=43024181.8.10.1349702850; language=de",
    // the '+ 1' in the following line assumes you want to keep the ';' character
    newCookie = cookie.substring(0,cookie.lastIndexOf(';') + 1);
console.log(newCookie);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MaudF/1/).

References:

- [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf).

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `replace()` method like this:

```
cookie = cookie.replace(" language=de", "");
```

or if the text could vary but the number of the characters remains the same

```
cookie  = cookie.substring(0, s.length - 12)
```

where 12 is the number of characters you want to remove from the end of the string

Answer (score 2):

If language can be anything (not just de) I would use a regex:

```
cookie = cookie.replace(/language=[^;]+;?/, "");
```

Which basically says replace `language=<anything that is not a ;>` with nothing